# Display window over full screen application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm working on a .Net (WPF/C#) application, the application displays notifications (similar to Growl notifications on OS X) at different times, I would like the notifications to display above all other windows, including when there is a full screened app (like a PowerPoint presentation).

Is there anyway to display a Window over a full screened app?

Comment: Search term is "Topmost". Don't forget to check out [TopMost is not TopMost always](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729369/topmost-is-not-topmost-always-wpf)

Comment: And then the next developer comes along and wants to write an application that can go full screen and even block out your notifications. And so we go around in another circle again. Raymond Chen has written some great posts about the [Walls and Ladders game](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/01/17/10257351.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to set `TopMost = true` parameter of this window?

also check this thread:
[Form top most?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324463/form-top-most)

Answer (score 0):

or you can use Popup instead, it will on top of any window or control.

Answer (score 0):

WPF.

```
private void Window_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Thread.Sleep(2000);
  this.Topmost = true;        
}
```

But this is not the best option. 
In full screen mode there is exclusive access to the display, and you can only display on top of this if you are allowed to implement it if it's a game in OpenGL, DirectX and BackBuffer to impose your data.