# Display the window on top of full-screen applications (games)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, desktop

How do I display a window on top of a full-screen app, in my case it's a game?

Since the game uses the same type of Topmost in full screen mode, it overlaps my window, how do I fix it if possible?

Comment: But this is not the best option. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228325/display-window-over-full-screen-application/51335334#51335334

Comment: WPF.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228325/display-window-over-full-screen-application/51335334#51335334 But this is not the best option.

Comment: "Not the best option" Then why are we searching for every related post just to link to it...?